# Blackberry Eclipse plugin and emulator

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I installed the following installation packages to develop Blackberry apps using the included emulators. I first installed them on a MacBook Pro, virtualizing Windows 7 x86 with VMware. Everything worked fine; I created a quick HelloWorld app and it compiled and ran successfully in the emulator. I did no other configuration. I installed the same app on my desktop PC with Windows 7 x64. I installed the exact same items. When I choose to run with the Blackberry Emulator, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Here's the file list:

- BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.0.0.67
  (This includes Eclispe)
- jdk-6u18-windows-i586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I removed JDK and the JDE Blackberry plugin.

I reinstalled JDK 6.

I reinstalled the JDE Blackberry plugin into a different directory other than Program Files. So I installed it at `c:\rim\eclispe`

I started up eclipse and opened my workspace, started the simulator and it finally started and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the same 32-bit version on both your virtual and desktop versions?

If so, I know the 32-bit version /should/ work on Win7 x64, but is it maybe not compatible? Do you need to just get a 64-bit version for your desktop?

Comment: On the Blackberry site I don't see an x64 version.

https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=AC44596FD197101932FFB572DFBC129C

Comment: Anything get generated in the Event Viewer when you launch the app? Sometimes there is a hidden error message that gets logged, but no associated dialog box.